# tfestimators error every time I call feature_columns()

Tags: r, tensorflow

I have a fresh Windows 10 install of R, RStudio, Python 3.6.8, TensorFlow, and the tfestimators library. However, whenever I execute the feature_columns() function, for example:

feature_cols <- feature_columns(column_numeric("test_column_name"))

...I get this error message:

Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) :
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.feature_column.feature_column' has no attribute 'numeric_column'

Any idea how to solve this?

I've restarted RStudio and Windows several times, reinstalled Python (This error occurs using both versions I've tried, 3.7 and 3.6.8), reinstalled the tfestimators package, and reinstalled TensorFlow. Same error always occurs.

Comment: what is your tensorflow version? Also did you load the tfestimator library with library(tfestimators) before calling feature_columns?

Comment: I'm using R version 3.5.3, and yes I called library(tfestimators) before calling feature_columns().

I've now tried this on a second machine, and the same problem occurs. One machine is Windows 10, the other Windows 8.

Comment: TensorFlow version is 1.13.1.